# Filtering the list of files based on the value obtained from another file (Apache Camel File component)

Tags: apache-camel

I need to create a file filter (to pick files from a folder) based on the content received from another file.
I set up a route like this:

**File1 Url ->  pollEnrich(File2 Url with filter, aggregationStrategy) -> log**

But the issue is that in pollEnrich, the value obtained from File1 is not available. Hence I am not able to create a filter based on which I have to pick the files from Folder2.

I tried both the filer option in the URL as well as the programmatic filter (by extending GenericFileFilter class). Any suggestions are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Recall the fact from [content-enricher](http://camel.apache.org/content-enricher.html),

> pollEnrich only accept one message as response

The pollEnrich will collect single file when call with file component. Thus, you should use file component with `fileName` option inside pollEnrich to collect single file and use while loop to call pollEnrich multiple time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I now understand, but one question - even if it gets one response by collecting single file, why is the filter not working? I am using Camel version 2.20, so the limitation that Camel can't use information in the current exchange no longer applies as per Camel documentation. I think I should use recipient list for my original requirement - let me check that and will update.

Comment: My bad..NOT recipient list. Either need to use loop. Or aggregator EIP

Comment: I changed the approach. I polled each file, enriched the content with the other single file (added as a header) and then used filter EAP to only accept the files which satisfies the condition. Thanks very much!